# numerical argument for $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Say $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with $K$-valued entries, $K$ a field. 
There is an 'abstract' argument showing this implies $BA=I$, namely that $AB=I$ implies $A$ is surjective, so it is injective by rank-nullity, so its right inverse must be its left inverse. My question is whether there is some other, more 'numerical' argument showing this, since obviously one can interpret $AB=I$ as some system of equations. The argument should use (I think) the fact that $K$ is a field, since rank-nullity does not work over general modules. So somewhere in the argument division should be involved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are basically asking for Cramer's rule.

Comment: You can find many, many answers in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

Answer (score 3):

An algebraic argument in terms of equations ("numerical") is possible, using the determinant. Since $1=\det I=\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, we know that $\det(A)\neq 0$ so that the inverse $A^{-1}$ exists. Hence $AB=I$ gives $B=A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}$, so that $BA=A^{-1}A=I$.

Comment: This is nice. I wonder whether there is an even more elementary approach.

Comment: @M.Van Possibly $BA=A^{-1}ABA=A^{-1}A=I$,

Comment: no, @J.G. , you just assumed $A$ is invertible!

Comment: @M.Van No; I was suggesting a simplification of the part of the argument that comes after invertibility is established.